# No data available in datatable when sort or searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable which is being populated after an ajax call when the page loads. The datatable is populated as expected, but when I click to sort or search, it shows a No data available message and all data previously populated is gone.

I tried to populate it by creating the columns via jquery and via html and search/sort is not working both ways.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/list",
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        error: function(response, textStatus) {
            if (response.status == "401") {
                location.href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pages/login.jsp";
            } else {
                alert("error");
            }
        },
        success: function(response, textStatus) {
            populateTable(response)
        }
    });
    function populateTable(response) {
        $(function() {
            $("#dataTable tbody").html("");
            $.each(response, function(i, item) {
                var body = "<tr>";
                body+= "<td>" + item.name + "</td>";
                body+= "<td>" + item.surname + "</td>";
                body+= "</tr>";
                $( "#dataTable tbody" ).append(body);
            });
        });
        $( "#dataTable" ).DataTable();
        
    }
            
});
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect to be able to sort and search without getting the No data available message

Comment: Hard to help without seeing your configuration. Post the relevant code

Comment: Just updated it

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is not working because may be you are adding rows manually.

By doing so you are not utilizing all features provided by Datatable.

Please try something like this, its more cleaner

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/api/list"
            "type": "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name " },
            { "data": "surname" }
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that and it still gives the "No data available" message

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following example as basis and it is working fine now

`http://jsfidsdle.net/gh/get/jquery/2.2/chennighan/RapidlyPrototypeJavaScript/tree/master/lesson4/`